# Box model of Block element within another block element

Tags: css

For the box model of a **block element within another block element** of fixed dimensions, for example:

```
   <div style="height: 200px; width:200px;">
    <figure></figure>
   </div>
```

do the inner block-level element's dimensions (eg: `<figure>`) have to fit in the outer one's dimensions (eg: `<div>`) - i.e: less than? and if not, how can we force them to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting the child element dimesions to 100%.

```
div>figure {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

To prevent child `img` tags from getting distorted you should set the `img` tag's height to auto and max-width to 100%.

```
div>figure>img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't have to be the case, you can determine whichever style attributes you want.

If you want to contain it however, you would probably want to use the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) attribute:

```
<div style="height: 200px; width:200px; overflow: hidden;">
  <figure></figure>
</div>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ay913r3c/)

Answer (score 0):

A block box may exceed the dimensions of its containing block for any number of reasons, and such a box is said to overflow its containing block. You can prevent this from happening by giving the box a max-width:

```
figure {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```